# WPF databinding colored items in a combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox, code-behind

**I have read a couple of other articles, but none have been able to answer my combination of issues**
I have a ComboBox in which i want to display items in different colors, this can be done by using a ComboBoxItem and settings its Background. My problem arises when i want to store my CategoryDTOs in different colors and later be able to extract them again. What i need to have displayed is just the color and the Name property of my CategoryDTOs. And i must then be able to get the CategoryDTO object from the SelectedItem property. I have attempted various solutions using ItemsSource, DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath. But have only accomplished this [image: Picture of the combobox]
As is seen it displays the colors, but only displays the Name of the selected CategoryDTO and i havent even tested if SelectedItem works correctly yet.
Below i will put the code i use.

```
[Serializable]
public class CategoryDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...not important...
}


CategoryDTO[] categories = await _isd.GetCategoriesAsync();
comboBoxCategory.ItemsSource = categories.Select(c => new CategoryComboBoxItem(c)).ToList();
comboBoxCategory.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
comboBoxCategory.SelectedValuePath = "Name";

public class CategoryComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
{
    public CategoryComboBoxItem(CategoryDTO category)
    {
        this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(category.Color);
        this.Content = category;
    }
}
```

I dont have anything special specified in the .xaml so i will leave that part out. Beyond this i would like to be able to set the SelectedItem using the Name property. I very much prefer the answers to be in code-behind, but if it is stupidly complicated .xaml only answers are just as fine. I dont have any experience with MVVM, i can assume it will be suggested. I will of course expand my knowledge on that matter as i delve deeper into WPF, but right now i just would like this to work.
**This is not homework**

**EDIT: forgot to list errors i also get**

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=HorizontalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'CategoryComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'HorizontalContentAlignment' (type 'HorizontalAlignment')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'CategoryComboBoxItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='CategoryComboBoxItem'

Comment: The error you received is due to an error in binding, which is set up in your XAML file. Can you show your XAML markup?

Comment: Hi Jay T. As stated i dont perform any bindings in the XAML. The only thing in the XAML is the empty ComboBox. I believe the errors come from misuse of binding in code-behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do this properly with WPF, I think you need a better understanding of the `DataContext` and how it works. I wrote a blog post just for linking on SE for this: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/). I'd highly recommend making sure you understand the `DataContext` before doing anything with WPF.

Your overall idea is you want to bind a `ComboBox` to a list of `CategoryDTO` items, and have the `SelectedValue` property be set to the `Name`.

```xml
<!-- create a ComboBox -->
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" SelectedValuePath="Name">
    <!-- Add a custom Style to the individual items in combobox -->
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <!-- In custom style, bind background color -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Color}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

You can either set the items for your ComboBox with a binding if your DataContext is set correctly

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList}" ..>
```

Or with code behind

```
MyComboBox.ItemsSource = CategoryList;
```

This will also sync up your `ComboBox.SelectedItem` with the selected `CategoryDTO` item in your list, so you can directly cast it to do something with it

```
CategoryDTO selected = (CategoryDTO)MyComboBox.SelectedItem;
DoSomethingWithSelected(selected);
```

or bind it so it's easy to use from the DataContext

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory}" ..>
```

```cs
// Can now use SelectedCategory directly
DoSomethingWithSelected(SelectedCategory);
```

Note: Depending on the data type of your `.Color` property, you may need to use a `Converter` to convert the `.Color` value to a `SolidColorBrush` for the `.Background` property. Should be plenty of examples of converters online, or just ask if you need help.

Comment: Hi Rachel thanks for the quick answer. I will try out your solution ASAP and then come back with feedback. I will also make sure to read up on your article as it seems, judging by your reply, that you hit the nail in regards to my question.

Comment: Tested it and it works perfectly. Of course the color stuff is giving some errors but i will just add a converter as proposed. It should be quite simple given that my Color property is of System.Windows.Media.Color type. Thank you, i will mark this the answer.

Comment: @LuqJensen Good to hear! Good luck with your project :)